# Missing namespace on the same version of framework

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

I have two the same applications based on .net core.

First is on docker container, where I have 1.0.4 version of .net core.

Second is on my virtual machine Ubuntu 16.0.4 where I have 1.0.4 version of .net core too.

The problem is that when I want to use Claims on docker container based application, the Claims namespace cannot be found, but on Ubuntu vm, everything is ok.

Why is that? 
Both applications uses the same .net core framework so why I can't find Claims namespace on my docker container?

It may sounds weird but, I have 3 solutions, in first solution Claims namespace is available, but on the rest doestn't

There are csproj files.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Evento.Infrastructure\Evento.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Second

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Evento.Core\Evento.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging " Version="1.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Third

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with .net on docker containers. But I can give you a pointer to check. When running Virtual machine and a docker container, lot of things could be different.

Your VM could have a bash_profile with some PATH settings which may be missing on docker. Also your docker container will only be running the main process while in your VM other services could be running. This may or may not have an impact on your code.